# List Blobs in Azure Storage Container including Metadata

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am creating list of `Blobs` in a container and iterating through them.
However every single Blob's `Metadata` dictionary remains empty. I understand I need to populate / fetch them.

There is `BlobContainerClient.GetProperties` method which gets metadata, but no blobs itself.

How can I get list of Blobs with its Metadata populated so can iterate through Blobs, get its name, properties but also `Metadata` by a `Key`?

```
{
    string BlobPrefix = "prefix";
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient("connectionstring", "docrepo");
    var blobList = containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: BlobPrefix);

    foreach (var blob in blobList)
    {
        Console.Writeline(blob.Name);
        Console.Writeline(blob.Properties.CreatedOn.Value.UtcDateTime);
        Console.Writeline(blob.Metadata.Item("KeyName"));
    }
}
```

Using .NET v12 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass traits parameter as `BlobTraits.Metadata` this means the blob's metadata should be included.

Example

```
var blobList = containerClient.GetBlobs(BlobTraits.Metadata, BlobStates.All, BlobPrefix);
```